# Why don't Material Icons render in phantom js?

Tags: javascript, css, phantomjs, webfonts

Recently I'm making some experiments with phantom js to take screenshots of html code but I'm getting a estrange error with materialize icons font.

I have made a demo html like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons' rel='stylesheet'> 
    <style>
         html {
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
         }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      Hello this is using roboto
      <i class='material-icons'>favorite_border</i>
  </body>
</html>
```

Roboto is working great but material icons do not work. The following image is the result I get:
[image]

And this should be what i get:

[image]

I think that is because material icons use

```
-webkit-font-feature-settings: 'liga'
```

and phantomjs do not support it, am I right?. Font awesome works just fine.
Any clue?

I'm runing it in ubuntu server 16.04 lts and phantom js is 2.1.1
Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this has been fixed in the latest beta 2.5 version of phantomjs, see https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/14885.

Another solution is to self-host the web front. If you're serving the font from your own server, phantomjs has no problem rendering it.

Answer (score -1):

Your example is ok!!!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons' rel='stylesheet'> 
    <style>
         html {
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
         }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      Hello this is using roboto
      <i class='material-icons'>favorite_border</i>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know the html is right but phantom js do not render the heart